# Curl program getting captcha in result

Tags: php, curl

I am making a curl request to a website that doesn't have a captcha when accessed by web browser but for some reason has one when accessed with CURL. How can I make it so I just get the response of as if I was using my browser which wouldn't show a capatcha? This is mostly about learning how to use CURL effectively like a browser would to access web content. Here's my CURL code:

```
    $url = "example.com";
    $var = "Var";
    $var1 = "Var1";
    $var2 = "Var2";
    $var3 = "Var3";
    $var4 = "Var4";


$fields = array(
                        'var' => urlencode($var),
                        'var1' => urlencode($var1),
                        'var2' => urlencode($var2),
                        'var3' => urlencode($var3),
                        'var4' => urlencode($var4)
                );

//url-ify the data for the POST
$fields_string = "";
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($ch);
}
//close connection
curl_close($ch);

if (isset($error_msg)) {
    echo "Curl Error: '$error_msg'<br>";
}

echo "Result: $result<br>";
exit("exiting at 49");
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it returning google reCaptcha?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @yak0d3 . No, it's just numbers in a little and letters in a little box. I'm mainly wondering why don't I get the same result as if I was in a browser and how can I make it so I get the same result.

Comment: Because the website you are visiting is smart enough to know which one is a bot or at least which one is more suspicious.
There could be a lot of reasons, for example that website might be giving first visitors cookies, or checking the referrer url etc...

Comment: @yak0d3 I tried changing the referrer to no avail. Any other tips?